# twisted how to set and get headers on Echo server?

Tags: python, twisted

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor, endpoints
class Server(protocol.Protocol):

    def connectionLost(self, *args):
        print('Connection lost')

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)


class buildFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Server()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    reactor.listenTCP(8000, buildFactory())
    reactor.run()
```

How can I set and get server/client headers?
I've googled all over but the answers I've found required you to create a http server.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation here:
https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.0.0/api/twisted.web.http.Request.html

You are looking for the particular getHeader section
https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.0.0/api/twisted.web.http.Request.html#getHeader

```
def getAllHeaders(self): (source)
    Return dictionary of all headers the request received.
```

Comment: How would I mix the two, can the class inherit both Protocol and Request? The reason I need  the headers is Im attempting to make a streaming server and a source client to stream audio/video live. So getting the GET and setting custom headers is needed.